# Why is module.js file not running in the browser

Tags: typescript, systemjs

the code is not running and nothing is being output to the console like if i try console.log("random text"); in module.ts it doesn't logs anything to the console

Here I am basically trying to run modules in my typescript project. So I installed systemjs included it in  added config. added module "system" in tsconfig. but its still not working

```js
import { add } from "./function1";
import { subtract } from "./function2";
import { Person } from "./interface";

const John: Person = {
    name: "John",
    lastname: "Doe",
    greet(): void {
        console.log(`Hello, ${this.name} ${this.lastname}`);
    }
}
const addition = add(3, 3);
const subtraction = subtract(5, 2); 

console.log("Random Text"); //Doesnt Work



PACKAGE JSON
{
  "name": "assignment_4.3",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "typescript modules app",
  "main": "module.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "systemjs": "^0.20.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev":"lite-server"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "typescript",
    "modules"
  ],
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

```css
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module":"system",
        "target": "es5",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "outFile": "./module.js"
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">   
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    
    <script>
        SystemJS.config({
            baseUrl: '/',
            defaultExtensions: true
        });

        SystemJS.import('./module.js');
    </script>
</body>

</html>

Output HTML =====================

<body data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" cz-shortcut-listen="true"><script id="__bs_script__">//<![CDATA[
document.write("<script async src='/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.18.13'><\/script>".replace("HOST", location.hostname));
//]]></script><script async="" src="/browser-sync/browser-sync-client.js?v=2.18.13"></script>


<script>
    SystemJS.config({
        baseUrl: '/',
        defaultExtensions: true
    });

    SystemJS.import('module.js');
</script>


</body>
```

Comment: Why should there be anything on the console? You have a `greet` method that has a `console.log` statement but it is not being called anywhere. Is there something I'm missing, or perhaps something you missed to include in your question?

Comment: I had called that function earlier but it's still not working

Comment: even when i add console.log("random text") to module.ts it doesnt logs to the console

Comment: Please don't add distracting text like "why is no one answering" to your question's title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `tsc` to produce a SystemJS bundle and then you use `System.import` to load the bundle. Loading a bundle only *registers* the modules in the bundle. It does not *execute* the modules in the bundle: they still have to be requested.

When you use `outFile` you're saying "put all my modules in the same file" and this is a bundle. This creates a file with the module names exactly as you put in your TypeScript code. So if they don't have extensions there, then they don't have extensions in the produced bundle. You can see that by looking at the file that `tsc` produces:

```
System.register("module", [], function (exports_1, context_1) {
    "use strict";
    var __moduleName = context_1 && context_1.id;
    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            console.log("MODULE");
        }
    };
});
```

#### If you don't want to use a bundle

Change your `tsconfig.json` to remove `outFile`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module":"system",
        "target": "es5",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": true
    }
}
```

Change your SystemJS configuration to this:

```
    SystemJS.config({
      baseUrl: './',
      packages: {
        '': {
          defaultExtension: "js"
        },
      }
    });
```

The setting to add default extensions is `defaultExtension` in the singular and it is valid inside `packages`.

And let SystemJS add the `.js`, so import `module` rather than `module.js`:

```
SystemJS.import("module");
```

#### If you want to use a bundle

Change your `tsconfig.json` to give your bundle a name that is different from your module, as this will help clear confusion:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module":"system",
        "target": "es5",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "outFile": "bundle.js"
    }
}
```

And [declare the bundle](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#bundles) in your SystemJS configuration:

```
   SystemJS.config({
        baseUrl: './',
        bundles: {
          "bundle.js": ["module"],
        },
    });
```

Just as above you should import without the extension:

```
SystemJS.import("module")
```

---

This is an aside but I recommend not naming your module `module` because, besides not describing what the module is about, it hurts portability. AMD loaders for instance, reserve the module name `module` for an kind of virtual module provided by the loader.

Comment: whats the reason behind not giving extension to module in the bundle. does that mean when a call is made to bundle.js it loads module? I cant seem to understand how this thing is working

Comment: When you import the module in TypeScript you import `"something"`, not `"something.js"` or `"something.ts"`. `tsc` does not mess with this and keeps the module name as-is. This allows for maximum flexibility.  So the code can be used in a situation where all the TypeScript has been pre-compiled to `.js` files. You just need to have the loader look for the same module name with a `.js` appended. And the same code can be used in a situation where the TypeScript is compiled on the fly. In this case the module loader would be configured slap a `.ts` at the end of the module name.

Comment: Hey thanks, Louis. I Really appreciate your response and answers. One last thing Id like to ask is where can I get to learn more about all this, other than from the documentation.

Comment: I wish there were a nice learning resource I could point you to, but I don't know of one. What I learned was through trial and error, and reading the source code of SystemJS, `tsc`, etc.

Comment: It is so ridiculous how difficult it is to get an environment setup due to lack of documentation. Thank you for this solution!